# How can I install spcopula package

Tags: python, r

I have a problem whit installing spcopula package I geet this error:
Erreur : package or namespace load failed for ‘spcopula’:
 package ‘spcopula’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version
can any one hep me with that 
Thank you so much friends